# User Authentication Best Practices for single SignOn in Azure

Tags: azure, authentication, single-sign-on

I need a solution for the User Authentication Best Practices for single SignOn in Azure.

Please assist me

Comment: Use Azure Active Directory

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to configure an application for single sign-on. Choosing a single sign-on method depends on how you application is configured for authentication.

Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on#choosing-a-single-sign-on-method)

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_5jA0h0tCcypVC3r&Q_CHL=gl
>